# MS Graph API - List Children in DriveItems is failing with 404(itemNotFound)

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the API `v1.0/sites/:id/drive/items/:parent/children` to fetch the children informations of the drive item. I'm able get the response for some sites but for couple of sites I end up with the error 404(`itemNotFound`).

I passed `siteId` in place of `:id` & `parentReferenceId` in place of `:parent`.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "itemNotFound",
        "message": "The resource could not be found.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-03-15T05:25:34",
            "request-id": "2afc519e-95b0-45b0-bd91-3c716154cdcd",
            "client-request-id": "2afc519e-95b0-45b0-bd91-3c716154cdcd"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try this url pattern to get list of files and sub-folders

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SITE_ID>/drives/<DRIVE_ID>/root:<PATH_TO_NESTED_SUB_FOLDERS>:/children
```

Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/9e9145345-7f9j-4695-8701-bae4c2d8a553/drives/b!HTaRnpV7lUaKdgmdflilU5eQE4tMetVNifXIJN28qvp68vQzkrpfTLPMl6eBQi_4/root:/InnerFolder/InnerFol2:/children
```